# How to create mongodb query using spring jpa

Tags: spring, mongodb, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, spring-mongo

I have an sample application on spring-jpa using mongodb.
I have my service class as

```
import java.util.List;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;
import javax.persistence.Query;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Isolation;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Propagation;
//import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Propagation;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;


@Component
public class Test  {

    @PersistenceContext
         EntityManager em;
         EntityManagerFactory emf;

         @Transactional(readOnly = false, isolation = Isolation.DEFAULT, propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED)
    public String persist(Details details) {
             Query query = em.createNativeQuery("db.Details.findOne(username= "+details.getUsername()+"& password= "+details.getPassword(), Details.class);
             List<Details> resultList = query.getResultList();
             System.out.println(query.toString());
             Object t = null;
                if (!em.contains(t)) {
                em.persist(details);
                em.flush();
                System.out.println("Persist successful ...");
                }
                em.clear();
                em.close();
            return "persist";
         }
}
```

Controller class

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
//import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.ui.ModelMap;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;

@Controller
public class HelloWorldController {

@Autowired
private Test test;

    @RequestMapping("/")
            public String hello() {
                return "hello";
    }
    @RequestMapping(value = "/hi", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String hi(@RequestParam("username") String username, @RequestParam("password") String password, ModelMap model) throws Exception{
        Details details = new Details();
        test.persist(details);
        model.addAttribute("username", details.getUsername());
        model.addAttribute("password", details.getPassword());
        return "hi";
    }

}
```

and my pojo class is

```
@Entity
@Table(name="Details")
public class Details {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.TABLE, generator = "details")
    @TableGenerator(name="details")
    @Column
    private int Id;
    @Column
    private String username;
    @Column
    private String password;
    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }
    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }
    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }
    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }


}
```

My application runs good but the data is not inserting into the database i am not sure on the **QUERY**. can any help me out what i need to make changes in query so that i can retrieve the data.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can not use spring-data-jpa to access mongo. You need to use spring-data-mongodb which uses different model, starting with its entity annotations.

The easiest way to access mongo is

- adding spring-data-mongodb dependency to your POM
- creating a `Repository` interface
- annotating your POJO acting as DAO at least with `@Document("aCollectionName")` and your id field with `@Id.

Let this serve you as minimun requirements to get it working. For specific details follow the [corresponding doc](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-mongo/docs/1.6.0.RELEASE/reference/html/) and [tutorial](http://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-mongodb/).

Comment: Guess so, but never tried it. My advice is always limited by my experience.

Comment: I think i need to research more because i think it may be possible. but i need the correct query. and ill definitely follow your sugestion.thanks for the response.

Comment: Why can't we use spring-data-jpa to access mongo?